# I want to write a code which reads the data of a file in blocks of 16 bytes only?

Tags: c#, file, byte, arrays

Can anyone help me in writing a code which reads data into byte array in range of 16 bytes only. It should be like a for loop in c/c++..first 16 bytes then next 16 bytes of the file.

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
 bytes=File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\SKY\\Desktop\\temp_1.txt");
```

In this sample all the bytes are read at once.

Is there any way to read the bytes separately or using a loop byte by byte or divide the data read into bytearray in other bytearrays of 16 bytes?

Comment: Did you took a look at the BinaryReader.ReadBytes method ? -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 1. Why are you reading a `.txt` file as binary rather than ASCII? 2. This will be very slow. 3. It would be better to read the whole thing, than just loop through your `bytes[]` array `for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i+=16) {...}`

Comment: thanks @DavidLively I was able to seperate the data using just loops